# Right way of implementing airpush ad in andengine live wallpaper?

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I like to know whats the right way of implementing airpush ad in andeneine live wallpaper.
In my and engine live wallpaper application i have a main activity, a settings activity and wallpaper service that extends the BaseLiveWallpaperService of andengine.In all of these I am calling the air push ads using an sync task like

```
airpush=new Airpush(getApplicationContext());
new AdCAllAsync().execute();
```

and AdCAllAsync  as inner class

```
private class AdCAllAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        airpush.startPushNotification(false);
        airpush.startIconAd();
        return null;
    }
}
```

1. Is it correct to write async task in my wallpaper service that extends BaseLiveWallpaperService .(I used async task otherwise it may slow down the whole exicution each time when the service life cycle runs)
2. Is it necessary to write airpush calls in service for getting the ads deleverd daily,because user is not going to open the settings and main activity dialy even if he was using the wallpaper
3. When user select live wallpaper directly from wallpaper chooser and set as wallpaper directly from their with out entering in to settings, The terms and conditions dialog box by air push not get displayed. and the wallpaper will works perfectly with default settings. ie: User is able to use app without ad(I am not sure do the app is served with out user confirmation).What is the right way to make sure that user is confirmed the terms and add is getting delivered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... No answers yet. I got a solution from Air push team itself :)

1)  About the async task inside wallpaper service  its work well.no issues reported yet.

2&3) 
  Answer to main issue - When user select live wallpaper directly from wallpaper chooser 
 This situation can be avoided by adding the airpush initialization inside the on create engine method,I tested it in my app and works well...,this solves the 2&3 issues

:)

Comment: I up vote your answer because you put effort to paste correct answer so other users can take benefit of it.